# Module Routes Not Working In Expess

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I originally wrote my routes in one api.js, but I figured there was a better way and went around the internet to see how people implement stuff.  I followed a couple of tutorials and came up with the following layout where server.js is my kickoff:

```
-app
--models
--routes
---index.js
---settings.js
---sources.js
server.js
```

I broke out my routes into settings and sources, called them in the index.js and required that in server.js.  I would expect everything to work, but nothing resolves a /settings or /sources when I test the routes.  I don't know what I'm missing, but I keep going over this and I figure it is probably something stupid that I'm not getting.  I don't know what part of the process I have wrong and I've been looking at it too long!  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

server.js

```
var routes = require('./app/routes')(app, express)
app.listen(config.port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + config.port + '!');
```

index.js

```
module.exports = function(app, express){
    require('./settings')(app, express);
    require('./sources')(app, express);
}
```

settings.js (sources.js very similar so I'll leave that out for brevity)

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Settings = require('../models/settings');

module.exports = function (app, express) {
    var router = express.Router();

    //route for settings
    router.route('/settings')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            //check to see if any records exists
            ...
        })
        .put(function (req, res) {
           ...
        });

    return router
}
```

**Update:**
I got rid of my index.js file and put the app.use statements into the server.js file.  However, I wasn't able to get it to work without passing in the express argument.  I tried to follow the suggestions in the answers with settings-2.js, but no dice.

*What I did:*
server.js

```
//routes!
app.use('/', require('./app/routes/settings')(express));
app.use('/', require('./app/routes/sources')(express));
app.use('/settings2', require('./app/routes/settings-2'));

//start it up
app.listen(config.port);
```

new settings.js

```
module.exports = function (express) {
    var apiRouter = express.Router();

    //route for settings
    apiRouter.route('/settings')
        .get(function (req, res) {
           ...
        .put(function (req, res) {
            ...
        });

    return apiRouter;
}
```

settings-2.js 
This doesn't work at localhost:8080/settings2.  No errors, but the request just times out in Postman.

```
var Settings = require('../models/settings');
module.exports = function () {
    var apiRouter = require('express').Router();

    //route for settings
    apiRouter.route('/')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            //check to see if any records exists
           ...
        })
        .put(function (req, res) {
            ...
        });

    return apiRouter;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change how you're setting up your Router Middleware to work slightly differently. Instead of passing around the  `express` module just include `express` in your Routers. Additionally, there's not reason to pass around `app` since you're not even using it and its counterintuitive because it breaks the separation of concerns that you're trying to establish by using the Router Middleware.

I would say the best way to see how to structure your Express apps is to look at the way [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) structures the app it generates.

## server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(port);
```

## index.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var settings = require('./settings');
var sources = require('./sources');

module.exports = function() {
    router.use('/settings', settings);
    router.use('/sources', sources);

    return router;
}
```

## settings.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();

module.exports = function() {

    router.route('/')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            // do GET /settings route work
        })
        .put(function(req, res) {
            // do PUT /settings route work
        })

    return router;
}
```

## sources.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();

module.exports = function() {

    router.route('/')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            // do GET /sources route work
        })
        .put(function(req, res) {
            // do PUT /sources route work
        })

    return router;
}
```

Also in the above code, its probably preferable to get rid of the `index.js` code and migrate the two `/settings` and `/sources` middleware statements to `server.js` and reduce your code by 1 file. This would be a better practice.

Comment: Hey man!  Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!  It really helps.  I changed some things around and got rid of my index.js file.  I saw some articles online that said it was better to keep all those in one file.  I did run into an issue with the router.use() method.  I couldn't get my proutes to work unless I passed in the express argument to the function.  If you have time, check out my update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in your code snippets where you mount to router to the app.

For example:

index.js

```
module.exports = function(app, express){
    app.use('/', require('./settings')(app, express));
    app.use('/', require('./sources')(app, express));
}
```

---

I often see a layout that looks more like this:

```
app
|-- server.js
`-- routes
    |-- settings.js
    `-- sources.js
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/settings', require('./routes/settings'));
app.use('/sources', require('./routes/sources'));
app.listen(port)
```

settings.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = router

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { ... });
router.put('/', function(req, res, next) { ... });
```